# WPF component content not updating after view model change

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel, inotifypropertychanged

I have the following view model:

```cs
public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public string Watermark { get; set; } = "Loading...";
}
```

where `ObservableObject` is from `Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanging`.

I have the following XAML:

```xml
<xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
    <xctk:WatermarkTextBox.WatermarkTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding DataContext.Watermark, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"></ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xctk:WatermarkTextBox.WatermarkTemplate>
</xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
```

And lastly the following C# code:

```cs
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        // Assigning property of textbox directly with .Watermark = "" does not work

        // Updating view model property doesn't work either
        Model.Watermark = "Done";
    });
}
```

When the window loaded method gets called however, the watermark of the watermark textbox does not update to reflect its supposed new value, `"Done"`.

It might be a lack of general WPF understanding but if anyone could give a pointer as to why this might fail I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using `ObservableObject` properly.  It's not magic (unlike some solutions that use frameworks such as Fody), so you still have to do the work yourself to propagate changes.  Note the example in [the documentation](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/MVVM-Samples/blob/master/docs/mvvm/ObservableObject.md).

```
public class User : ObservableObject
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
    }
}
```

So you'll have to follow that pattern:

```
public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private string watermark;

    public ViewModel() 
    {
        Watermark = "Loading...";
    }

    public string Watermark
    {
        get => watermark;
        set => SetProperty(ref watermark, value);
    }
}
```